# Darle movimiento a botones mediante javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código en el cual intento darle una animación de movimiento a varios botones y que me da error:

```
//variables de la animación
var button0 = document.getElementById("button0");
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");

var pos0 = 0;
var pos1 = 0;
var pos2 = 0;
var pos3 = 0;

var direction0 = "down";
var direction1 = "down";
var direction2 = "down";
var direction3 = "down";

//proceso
function animateButton(button, pos, direction) {
    if (pos == 20) {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (pos == 0) {
        direction = "down";
    }

    if (direction == "down") {
        button.setAttribute("style", "top:" + pos + "px");
        pos++;
    } else if (direction == "up") {
        button.setAttribute("style", "top:" + pos + "px");
        pos--;
    }
}

setInterval( function() { animateButton(button0, pos0, direction0); }, 90 );
setInterval( function() { animateButton(button1, pos1, direction1); }, 90 );
setInterval( function() { animateButton(button2, pos2, direction2); }, 90 );
setInterval( function() { animateButton(button3, pos3, direction3); }, 90 );
```

¿A qué se puede deber?

Comment: Las variables `pos` y `direction` no son las variables que definiste de manera global para cada botón, el alcance de las primeras sólo llegan hasta  tu función, una vez terminada no se guardan los valores que haces de `pos++` y `pos--`

Comment: @Lixus, no entiendo muy bien a qué te refieres. He intentado pasar las globales por parámetros, abajo dentro de los setInterval a la función animateButton.

Comment: Adentro de tu función de animación `pos0 !== pos` y `direction0 !== direction` por lo que los valores de tus variables globales nunca cambiarán

Comment: @Lixus ¿No se supone que al ejecutar la función, pos adquiere el valor de pos0 y direction adquiere el valor de direction0 al ser estos pasados como parámetros? Si me pudieses poner un ejemplo corto de como hacerlo bien sería de gran ayuda.

Comment: No, las únicas variables que se pasan por referencia son los objetos, tipos nativos como String o Integers son por valor, así que adentro de la función `pos` y `direction` son nuevas variables independientes de tus variables globales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dices que si `pos == 20` entonces `direction = up`, y entonces abajo si `direction == up` luego haces otra cosa, lo mismo que si `pos == 0`, `direction = down`, y si `direction = down` otra cosa...

¿No crees que sea mas corto y la misma lógica, si dices esto ?

```
if (pos == 0) {
        button.setAttribute("style", "top:" + pos + "px");
        pos++;
    } else if (pos == 20) {
        button.setAttribute("style", "top:" + pos + "px");
        pos--;
    }
```

Además, no crees 4 `setInterval`, con uno te basta, de todas formas son por el mismo tiempo y si no fuera así, entonces si tendrías que crear mas para otros tiempos, seria:

Ejemplo:

```
setInterval(function(){

animateButton(button0, pos0, direction0);
animateButton(button1, pos1, direction1);
animateButton(button2, pos2, direction2);
animateButton(button3, pos3, direction3);
},90)
```

Esas cosas míralas, mientras menos código, menos tienes que analizar.

Edita tu pregunta con la descripción de los errores que tengas para entender mejor.

Te sugiero que estudies los `scope` del `this` en javascript, entendiendo eso encontraras tu error, estudia también las funciones `.call() .apply  .bind()`.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)** y gracias por tu respuesta. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78) y lee [cómo escribir una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.